Some of the keys on my Alienware 15 R3 laptop aren't working, what should I do?
I recently bought an Alienware 15 R3 laptop (2016). It worked perfectly fine when I used it for the first time, but I had to replace the battery since it wasn't holding a charge.
After I replaced the battery, some of the keys on the keyboard stopped working (T,P,3,4,5,3,9,.). When I just pressed random buttons on the keyboard, some of the keys started working again.
Then stopped working after 1-2 minutes. I tried deleting and reinstalling the keyboard drivers, but that didn't work. The USB keyboard and on-screen keyboard both work. I may have to go back and check and see if I did something to the keyboard.
I've seen other people have similar issues, so is there a solution to this?

Plug in a USB keyboard and test those same keys. If they work, then its not likely a software issue, but hardware.
Also, check the laptop's keyboard ribbon cable. Make sure it's properly aligned and inserted into its plug. While it's out, inspect the keyboard's ribbon cable for tears. If is still does not work, you might have to purchase a replacement keyboard.

Seems like a cable became loose after you replaced the battery. Try disassembling the setup just like you did when you swapped out batteries and look for loose cables. Even reseating already set cables might help.
